# React Native axios api call Shopify

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, shopify, shopify-app

Good morning guys, I try to fetch data from Shopify using this method. But it does not working.

> Request failed with status code 400

May you share your little experience ?
I'm working on React Native Project.

```
const api_key = "example-api-key";
    const password = "example-password";
    const version = "2021-07";
    const url = `https://${api_key}:${password}@store-example.myshopify.com/admin/api/${version}/products.json`;
    useEffect(() => {
        axios({
            method:'get',
            url:url
        }).then((result) => {
            console.log(result.data)
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    });
```

Comment: Do you get the error or is the data empty? Explain the issue.

Comment: @HymnZzy hi bro, it return error: Request failed with status code 400.

Comment: Try passing the credentials as a basic auth header instead of adding key and password in the url.

Comment: Indeed, Because when i did testing on Postman using Basic Auth it return me the data. In this case i don't know how to implement the code with axios bro. would you help me please.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely that the authentication is failing. Move the auth parameters to axios header. Try this

```
const username = "example-api-key";
const password = "example-password";
const version = "2021-07";
const url = `https://store-example.myshopify.com/admin/api/${version}/products.json`;
useEffect(() => {
    axios({
        method:'get',
        url,
        auth: { username,password }
    }).then((result) => {
        console.log(result.data)
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
});
```